# How to view name and profile of site guest user

Tags: force.com-sites, security, site.com, guest-user

I have sites in my Salesforce org. How do I view the name and profile of the giest user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Public Access Settings button on the Site record in Setup. That will give you the Profile. To get to the User, click Assigned Users button in the Profile.